# Keyboard not showing up in Devices and Printers

Tags: keyboard

my PS2 keyboard is not showing up in the Devices and Printers category. I upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 7, which is running fine. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: You can access keyboard settings in Control Panel

Comment: What make and model PC do you have? Please collect it from the serial number sticker, click [edit], and add it into the question. Does its motherboard have PS/2 ports at the back, or are you using a PS/2-USB adapter? If that's the case, plug it into a black or white USB port, not blue, yellow, or red. Also please advise that with [edit].

Comment: Question was answered by Apache. PS2 devices don't appear in Devices and Printers. I just assumed that attached devices showed up there. It's working fine, even without the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

- PS2 is not like USB, it is not Plug And Play.
- Make sure that any PS2 devices that you'd like to use are plugged in before the computer boots. They cannot be used otherwise.
- PS2 devices will not show up in Devices and Printers. Only USB and such shows up there. PS2 devices provide no other information about themselves. They just.. exist.

So, if your peripheral works, great, that's all you have to do.
If it does not, make sure you plug it in before the computer boots.

Comment: You are "spot on"! That's great info for future reference. In fact, the keyboard functions just fine. Your explanation really makes sense. I just "assumed" it should show up in the catagory. You guys are AWESOME!!